# Sum of all the elements of 3 different arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I want and optimized algorithm to find sum of each and every element of array.

for example let 3 array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4];
b = [5,6];
c = [8,9];
```

then final sum will be equal to:

`sum(1,5,8)+sum(1,5,9)+sum(1,6,8)+sum(1,6,9)+sum(2,5,8)...+sum(4,6,9)`

I tried doing but the algorithm I used had time complexity O(n^3), so I want anything less than this complexity.

Here is my algorithm:

```
sum = 0    
for(i=0;i<a.size();i++)
       for(j=0;j<b.size();j++)
          for(k=0;k<c.size();k++)
              sum = sum+a[i]+b[j]+c[k];
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. If you are trying to do what I think, that's a factorial time algorithm. edit your question.

Comment: Also that's not a 2d array.

Comment: @Makogan: The algorithm presented has more than one input size. Simply saying cubic or factorial time does not make sense because there are 3 arrays, each of arbitrary size. The complexity is the product of their sizes (can be deduced by the way the for loops are nested)

Answer (score 3):

For this example, `a`, `b` and `c` have 4, 2 and 2 elements respectively. If you want to add them in every combination, there will be `4 * 2 * 2 = 16` terms to add. In those terms, each element of `a` will appear 4 times, because it will be added to `2 * 2 = 4` combinations of elements of `b` and `c`. Similarly, each element of `b` (or `c`) will appear 8 times, because it will be added to each `4 * 2 = 8` combinations of each elements of `a` and `c` (or `b`).

So, in the final sum, each element of `a` will appear 4 times and each element of `b` and `c` will appear 8 times. Once you figure that out, you can do fewer number of multiplications and additions to get the result.(Just sum of elements of individual arrays and then multiply these sums by 4 , 8 and 8 respectively).

Comment: To further optimize, pre-compute the sum of each array, then multiply it by the product of the other two arrays' sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of `a` will appear in sums with each element of `b` and each element of `c`.

This means that every element in `a` will appear in a number of sums equal to `b.length * c.length`.

This is also easy to see from the brute force pseudo-code: (modified for readability)

```java
for i = 0 to a.length
   for j = 0 to b.length     // happens once for each i
      for k = 0 to c.length  // happens b.length times for each i
         sum += a[i] + ...   // happens b.length * c.length times for each i
```

Generalising this, we come up with the following algorithm:

- Sum all elements `a`, multiply the result by `b.length * c.length`.
- Sum all elements `b`, multiply the result by `a.length * b.length`.
- Sum all elements `c`, multiply the result by `a.length * b.length`.
- Return the above three values added together.

This is an `O(n)` algorithm, where `n` is the total number of elements or average number of elements per array.